# How to find the schematic diagram of a component in Multisim?

Tags: integrated-circuit, multisim

Could someone please tell me how to find the schematic diagram of a given conponent in Multisim,  I've been trying to understand how does the IC 74LS729  (SR latch) work but coudn't succeed mostly because this component doesn't behave like a normal SR latch would and  it also includes another input called S3 whose function is also unclear to me.

Any help would be more than welcome[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably works quite a bit like a [74LS279A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls279a.pdf).

There are two different types of latches inthe '279A. Out of the 4 latches, 2 have just one \$\bar{S}\$ input, and 2 have dual \$\bar{S}\$ inputs. The Multisim component appears to have just one of each of these types instead of two of each.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the [74LS279N](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/DM74LS279.pdf) (as opposed to the 74LS729 you mention in the text), you can look at the [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/DM74LS279.pdf) for the connection diagram.

Look at the actual pin numbers in the datasheet, rather than the names.  It should make sense after that.